# Brackets : How to only select (String) Instead whole ($String) like SublimeText.?

Tags: sublimetext, adobe-brackets

how to select only value instead $value by double-click in brackets.?

[SublimeText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5dUR.png)  $`String`

[Brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdi4P.png)  `$String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Sublime Text by default handles `$` as a word separator. You can change this by changing the settings.
If you want to change it only for the current syntax select in the main menu *Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific* (for everywhere select *Preferences > Settings*).

Now you see the default preferences on the left side and the syntax specific preferences on the right side. Search for the key `word_separators` on the left side and copy it to right side. Afterwards remove the `$` from the value. Ensure that the settings are a valid json object.

The result should look like this:

```js
{
    "word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
}
```